# SQL Group By Clause and Empty Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 query that I'm trying to assemble right now but I am having some difficulties.

I have a group by clause based on 5 columns: Project, Area, Name, User, Engineer.

Engineer is coming from another table and is a one to many relationship

```
WITH TempCTE
AS (
    SELECT htce.HardwareProjectID AS ProjectId
        ,area.AreaId AS Area
        ,hs.NAME AS 'Status'
        ,COUNT(*) AS Amount
        ,MAX(htce.DateEdited) AS DateModified
        ,UserEditing AS LastModifiedName
        ,Engineer
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY htce.HardwareProjectID
            ,area.AreaId
            ,hs.NAME
            ,htce.UserEditing ORDER BY htce.HardwareProjectID
                ,Engineer DESC
            ) AS row
    FROM HardwareTestCase_Execution AS htce
    INNER JOIN HardwareTestCase AS htc ON htce.HardwareTestCaseID = htc.HardwareTestCaseID
    INNER JOIN HardwareTestGroup AS htg ON htc.HardwareTestGroupID = htg.HardwareTestGroupId
    INNER JOIN Block AS b ON b.BlockId = htg.BlockId
    INNER JOIN Area ON b.AreaId = Area.AreaId
    INNER JOIN HardwareStatus AS hs ON htce.HardwareStatusID = hs.HardwareStatusId
    INNER JOIN j_Project_Testcase AS jptc ON htce.HardwareProjectID = jptc.HardwareProjectId AND htce.HardwareTestCaseID = jptc.TestcaseId
    WHERE (htce.DateEdited > @LastDateModified)
    GROUP BY htce.HardwareProjectID
        ,area.AreaId
        ,hs.NAME
        ,htce.UserEditing
        ,jptc.Engineer
    )
```

[image]

The gist of what I want is to be able to deal with empty Engineer columns.  I don't want this column to have a blank second entry (where row=2).

**What I want to do:**

1. Group the items with "row" value of 1 & 2 together.
2. Select the Engineer that isn't empty.
3. Do not deselect engineers where there is not a matching row=2.

I've tried a series of joins to try and make things work.  No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use `j_Project_Testcase PIVOT( MAX(Engineer) for Row in ( [1], [2] )` then select `ISNULL( [1],[2])` to select the `Engineer` value

I can give you a more robust example if you set up a SQL fiddle

Try reading this: [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)